# Feature selection using Binary PSO (BPSO)

Tags: hough-transform, particle-swarm

Hey I read about Feature selection using Binary PSO (BPSO) in paper titled "Face Recognition using Hough Transform based Feature Extraction" [paper here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915001337).
Can someone explain throughly to me how BPSO can be used for feauture selection? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to implement a Binary PSO. The Smallest Position Value technique is a common technique to use when implementing a BPSO.

Basically, the feature with the smallest position is considered as YES.